# GTX 760 software help needed for this nube

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have Ubuntu 14.10 desktop and a ASUS geforce gtx 760 graphics card.  I got the drivers to install just fine (with lots of reading). Now I need the software to go with it. I have the disk with the windows installation on it but need some help to get everything done right.  Or is this just a big train wreck about to happen, if so what options do I have so I can easily adjust settings for my graphics card?

Comment: What software are you referring to? Do you mean [nvidia-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nvidia-settings/)?

Comment: I think he means the gui for nvidia experience, that comes on the windows CD. I also think he installed the windows drivers under wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Windows software on Linux as an actual hardware controller. You'll have to stick with x server settings by nvidia

Comment: I knew that windows software wouldn't work.  But I can not find anything that will work on Ubuntu, that looks like a project that I am comfortable undertaking. That being said, If I dual boot windows 8.1 and get my graphics card settings set like I need them will the settings be applied to the ubuntu side also?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The x-server settings, after installing the proprietary drivers from the dash under 'additional drivers'

Comment: If you install the proprietary nvidia drivers, by going to 'Additional Drivers' in the dash, you should have some x-server settings in the dash as well, used as a control panel for nvidia cards.

Comment: your comments lead me to find the answer I was looking for.  How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: It already is, I just needed to make sure I was 100% clear. Thank you.